# Angular + bind to navigation property

Tags: angularjs, breeze, angular-ngmodel

my server side code

```
 public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string EmployeePhoto { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Person")]
    public virtual int PersonId { get; set; } // relates Employee to Person
}
```

I use breeze for dataservice on the clinet

```
var employee = manager.createEntity('Employee');
var person = manager.createEntity('Person');
employee.person = person;
```

the I bind to my viewModel (angular controller property like this)

```
vm.employee = employee
```

and I try to access in html like this

```
<input ng-model="vm.employee.person.firstName" placeholder="First Name" id="firstName" />
```

but it doesnt workout...

Help Plz

Comment: it may work capitalized? `vm.employee.Person.FirstName`

Comment: Show the code where you define `vm` in both the controller and the View? Is `var vm = this;` and do you have `ng-controller="FooCtrl as vm"`?

Comment: yes @NewDev 
    
var vm = this;

        vm.activate = activate;
        vm.title = 'New Employee';

        var entityName = model.entityNames.employee;

        vm.employee = undefined;

Comment: Don't you need to actually query the backend somewhere? There is really not enough code in your question to be able to debug.

Comment: What does "doesn't work out" mean? What's the behavior? Throws? Nothing displayed? Per @abel, we need to know what `NamingConvention` you are using. Per @New Dev, we need to know how you populated your `MetadataStore` (usually the first query does it). Can you verify in the debugger that `vm.employee.person.firstName` returns a value?